# SSIS Script Component - Process 1 Row of Json to Table

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, ssis, script-component

I'm new to SSIS. I'm trying get a field that contains a Json string from a table as the input, and convert the Json into a table as the output.  I have setup an Asynchronous Script Component in SSIS, selected the Json field as input column, and also created output columns, but I came across a few problems:

1. How can I get the value from the input?  I try to extract the input
   column to string in the "ProcessInputRow" method like

   string = Row.MData
   I get "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.BlobColumn' to 'string'"

   Or return "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.BlobColumn" when I try to convert it to string
2. Should I just write my code in "ProcessInputRow" because I can use
   OutputBuffer.AddRows to construct my output? And ignore
   "CreateNewOutputRows" as I cannot access the input data in
   "CreateNewOutputRows"?
3. Or any suggestion of better approach of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you need to use code similar to this inside your script transform:

var myString = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Row.MData.GetBlobData(0,Convert.ToInt32(Row.MData.Length)));

this should allow you to get the json stored in a blob as a string you my need to substitute Ascii for unicode depending on the specifics of your code.

Comment: Thanks, I got this sorted.